# Alloy discriminates between the same two signature instances in permutation

Tags: alloy

In the following alloy model:

```
sig Family{
    father: one Member,
    mother: one Member,
    daughter: set Member,
    son: set Member
}

sig Member{}

fact {
    all m:Member  | one m.~(father+mother+daughter+son)  
    (none->none) = (mother &  son) + (daughter & son) +(father & mother) + (father &  daughter) + (father & son)  + (mother & daughter)   
}

pred show(){}

run show for  12 but exactly 2 Family,  exactly 5  Member
```

there is no distinction between the *son* and *daughter* relations in the sense of constraints on them (At least as far as I understand) But when I run this model, it gives me 3 instances: it permutes *son* between two families, but it does not permutes daughter! Why this happens?

PS:
when I try it for exactly 1 Family the analyzer does not discriminate son and daughter but when I increase the Family to 2 or three the discrimination occurs!

Comment: It looks off-hand as if there is a shortcoming in the symmetry breaking:  it's failing to detect that the two instances you get involving sons are isomorphic, but succeeding in detecting the isomorphism for the cases involving daughter.  Interesting, but ... does it matter, or are you just curious?

Comment: sorry, I can not get what you mean exactly! I am interested to know the reason alloy acts this way. I even changed the son and daughter signatures literally but it keeps acting the same way (permuting sons but not daughters when I have more than one family) which was a surprise.

Comment: Alloy atoms are uninterpreted; from any instance of a model (as shown by the Analyzer) it is possible to permute the atoms and get another instance.  To avoid showing duplicate instances different in names but not structure (and to speed analysis), Alloy uses 'symmetry breaking' constraints which help eliminate duplicate solutions.  For pragmatic reasons, the symmetry breaking rules used are incomplete, and some isomorphic solutions creep through; your two sons instances are examples.  See Jackson, *Software Abstractions*, discussion after sec. 5.2.1.  Why sons and not daughters? Don't know.